# Why Do My Python Scripts Pause in Terminal?

Tags: python, windows, terminal, command-line-interface

I have some Python scripts which I am running in Windows using Command Prompt by entering the following command: `python -m scriptname`.

I have noticed that quite often, these scripts randomly pause and stop running. I can resume them by typing any key in Command Prompt, but I have no idea why this is happening or how to prevent it all together. Has anybody encountered a similar problem, and does anybody have any suggestions they may be able to offer?

Comment: When it "stops," check the title bar of the terminal window. Does the title begin with the text "Select", i.e., "Select Command Prompt"?

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the cmd window, and click on `properties`. Check if you have `QuickEdit Mode` on. If you do, uncheck that box.

This is a known issue for command prompt that if you click on the window, it will enter select mode, which will pause the program.